# How to search for libraries/headers in custom paths using waf?

Tags: c++, waf

I try to search for a library and headers in a waf wscript file. Generally, that's possible with:

```
def configure( conf ):
  conf.load( "compiler_cxx" )
  conf.check_cxx( lib = "thelib" )
  conf.check_cxx( header_name "header.hpp" )
```

That works fine on Unix-like systems, where libraries and headers are mostly in common places. However, I'd like to add custom search paths to the `check_cxx()` command, especially to give the users on Windows systems the chance to find the library, which is often somewhere in the file system.

I'm aware of the `libpath` argument, however it still needs to be filled somehow, and I wonder if there isn't a more general or even built-in solution I missed.

I'd also be happy to hear about other approaches, solutions or good practices for such things in waf.

Answer (score 4):

The best practice is to use the `use` facility of WAF for your check ([§10.3 of the wafbook](https://waf.io/book/#_library_interaction_use)) and define the paths for your external/system libs ([§10.3.3](https://waf.io/book/#_foreign_libraries_and_flags))

It will looks like :

```
def configure(conf):

    conf.load('compiler_cxx')
    conf.env.LIBPATH_MYLIB = ['/usr/local/lib']
    conf.env.INCLUDES_MYLIB  = ['/usr/local/include']

    if sys.platform == 'win32':
            conf.env.LIBPATH_MYLIB   = ['/custom/windows/path/lib']
            conf.env.INCLUDES_MYLIB  = ['/custom/windows/path/include']

    # use MYLIB in your check
    conf.check_cxx(lib = 'somelib', use = 'MYLIB', cxxflags = '-O2')

def build(bld):

    # Of course you can use the defined MYLIB in build ^^
    bld.program(source = 'main.cpp', use = 'MYLIB')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def build(bld):
    bld.program(
        ...
        stdlibpath=['list/of','various/paths','the/linker/checks/for','libraries'],
        ...
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Wafs C and C++ compilation tools respects environment variables on Windows too. So you would simply set `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` before running Waf:

```
> set CXXFLAGS=/IC:\\path\\to\\header.hpp-file
> set LDFLAGS=/LIBPATH:C:\\path\\thelib
> python waf configure build
...
```

`/I` and `/LIBPATH` are switches that Waf will pass to the C compiler and linker. In this case, Microsoft Visual C. Use `-I` and `-L` instead if you are using gcc or clang.